# My prefix gives off waves, My infix takes in waves

Tags: riddle, rhyme, affix-riddle

- My prefix gives off waves.
- My suffix under a bridge.
- My infix takes in waves.
- My whole that must forage.

Comment: if DeepThinker's answer is right (and it looks good), don't the three parts normally not overlap?

Comment: @SteveV No? At least not that I've heard of. Can you go into more detail? Thanks.

Comment: Well I could be wrong!  Wouldn't be the first time (today). :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Pretty sure this is SEARCH

> Prefix is SEA

> Suffix is ARCH

> Infix is EAR

> Whole is SEARCH